# Issue with google MarkerImage not displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, image-resizing

I am trying to resize some icons to display them on GMaps with MarkerImage but it doesn't work. If I load in the normal way, it works, code:

```
function addMyPos(latitud,longitud){
 posi = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud)
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: posi,
  map: map,
  icon: "../res/punto_negropru.png"
 });
}
```

But the image is too big, so I try to use a MarkerImage,but doesn't work:

```
function addMyPos(latitud,longitud){
 var imag = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
           "../res/sit_marron.png", 
           new google.maps.Size(26, 30), 
           new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
           new google.maps.Point(13,30) 
   );
posi = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud)
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: posi,
 map: map,
 icon: imag
 });
}
```

Note that I tried to pass all kind of numbers to point,size..etc and I can't resize, the image just disappears always.Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have edited MarkerImage in your code. Try visiting [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MarkerImage` has been removed from their API recently, I believe.  Try changing that part of your code to this:

```
var imag = {
    url: "../res/sit_marron.png", 
    size: new google.maps.Size(26, 30), 
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(13,30),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(13, 15)
};
```

(Change the value of `scaledSize` to whatever is appropriate.  I just picked half size as an example.)